# CTRL-ALT-L not locking screen Ubuntu 15.04 w/ Gnome

Tags: gnome, 15.04, lock

Title says it all.

This is a feature I need.  It's probably something easy, but googling it just gave me a hodgepodge of unrelated stuff.

Comment: Did you try the 'Super' (or 'Windows') key?

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver`

Comment: It gives me:  <Primary><Alt>l

Answer (score 4):

You can set the Keyboard Shourtcut for locking the screen and other operation in the keyboard settings:
[image: Gnome Control Center > Keyboard > Shortcuts > System]

Comment: It's set there, but it does not work.

This is very strange.

Comment: Does 'Super'+'L' or another combination work?

Comment: Nope.  I am a bit baffled.

Answer (score 4):

I've the same problem and it's somehow related to the lightdm display manager. I use the following workaround. Right after logging in I open a terminal and run:

```
/etc/init.d/lightdm restart
```

This will restart the display manager and also kills the current X session. After logging in again all keyboard shortcuts should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **GSettings configuration tool**.

Open a terminal and fire this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screensaver "<Ctrl><Alt>l"
```

The default value is `<Super>l`

Comment: This seems not to be working.

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1427877), also available as [this GNOME bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747745) where many shortcut keys stop working. If you have GNOME 3.16 I would look into it. There is not a fix out yet, but it is marked as high importance, so a fix may be released soon.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be it.  I guess I will  just wait and watch for updates

Answer (score 1):

The default keyboard shortcut has been changed.  The new shortcut is <kbd>Super + L</kbd>.  "Super" means the Windows key, typically on the left side of the keyboard just below <kbd>Z</kbd>.

If you'd prefer to use the old <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> shortcut (or anything else) then you can do so by opening the Settings app and choosing Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> System -> Lock Screen, and re-assigning the action to a new shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are still having this issue, but the same thing was happening to me and I solved it by switching from `lightdm` to `gdm`. Install `gdm` if you don't already have it, and then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`. Hope this works for you too!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom shortcut in the shortcut menu.  The command should be:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Pressing `windows(button next to left ctrl) + L` which also locks the computer. It works for me, hopefully help you as well.